# How do I create a list of all my folder ('train') images in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I have 399 images in my folder called 'train_images', I'd like to create a list of all these images in my openCV like ('cv2.imread(list)')

```
TRAIN_DIR = 'train_data/'
TEST_DIR = 'test_data/'

train_path = glob.glob("train_data/*.ppm")

train_path.sort()

train_images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in train_path]


train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 512, 512, 1).astype('float32')

cv2.imshow('image',train_images[0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Ok, this code seems to do exactly that, what is the problem?

Comment: #train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 512, 512, 1).astype('float32')

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: refer my answer here - it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451257/9153298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to load all images into memory? A better way would be if you read the directory and create a list with the path of all images.

```
def ReadFiles(Path):
    ImageList = list()
    LabelList = list()

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = os.listdir(Path)

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        if(os.path.isdir(Path + os.path.sep + File)):
            for Image in os.listdir(Path + os.path.sep + File):
                # Add the image path to the list
                ImageList.append(Path + os.path.sep + File + os.path.sep + Image)

                # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
                LabelList.append(File.split(".")[0])
        else:
            ImageList.append(Path + os.path.sep + File)

            # Add a label for each image and remove the file extension
            LabelList.append(File.split(".")[0])

    return ImageList, LabelList
```

Now you can store all images into an `HDF5` file and/or use a `generator` to load the files in small batches into the network. The advantage is that you can use image databases for the training which are larger than your physical RAM. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-custom-keras-generators-fe815d992c5a) and [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/) if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
train_images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in train_path]
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 512, 512, 1).astype('float32')
```

Problem is that `train_images` is a list, not a numpy array. Only numpy arrays have the `reshape` and `astype` methods. But the solution is quite simple, just convert `train_images` into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

train_images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in train_path]
train_images = np.array(train_images)

train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 512, 512, 1).astype('float32')
```