# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

I have a dataset with 5 labels

```
def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  class_names = ['daisy' 'dandelion' 'roses' 'sunflowers' 'tulips']
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  # Integer encode the label
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # resize the image to the desired size
  return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

If I change this code with other dataset having 2 labels, `class_names = ['dog', 'cat']` I find this error
  `TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, complex64, int64, qint8, quint8, qint32, bfloat16, uint16, complex128, float16, uint32, uint64`
So how I can update  `def get_label(file_path)`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. Following the idea of ​​the last post:

```
one_hot = tf.dtypes.cast(parts[-2] == class_names, dtype = tf.int16)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in this line `img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)` , img is image name instead of actual image.
To resolve this problem you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451243/17692123)

It worked for me. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that tf.argmax requires one of these data-types (I can't test this right now)

```
float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, complex64, int64, qint8, quint8, qint32, bfloat16, uint16, complex128, float16, uint32, uint64
```

so all you need to do is convert the output of

```
one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
```

to int, the "==" evaluates to True/False which is probably not allowed.